# extract conent using regex within <! >

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

```
 html="""text <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
    jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, { "basePath": "/", "googleanalytics": { "trackOutbound": 1, "trackMailto": 1, "trackDownload": 1, "trackDownloadExtensions": "7z|aac|arc|arj|asf|asx|avi|bin|csv|doc|exe|flv|gif|gz|gzip|hqx|jar|jpe?g|js|mp(2|3|4|e?g)|mov(ie)?|msi|msp|pdf|phps|png|ppt|qtm?|ra(m|r)?|sea|sit|tar|tgz|torrent|txt|wav|wma|wmv|wpd|xls|xml|z|zip" }, "spamspan": { "m": "spamspan", "u": "u", "d": "d", "h": "h", "t": "t" } });
    //--><!]]>"""
```

Help me extract the content between `<!` and `>`.

Comment: can u post regular expression code

Comment: Avinash can u give me a regex for extracting content between quotes   " "  from html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

Use DOTALL modifier `(?s)` in-order to make dot in your regex to match also the linbe breaks.

> extract conent using regex within `<! >`

```
>>> html="""text <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
    jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, { "basePath": "/", "googleanalytics": { "trackOutbound": 1, "trackMailto": 1, "trackDownload": 1, "trackDownloadExtensions": "7z|aac|arc|arj|asf|asx|avi|bin|csv|doc|exe|flv|gif|gz|gzip|hqx|jar|jpe?g|js|mp(2|3|4|e?g)|mov(ie)?|msi|msp|pdf|phps|png|ppt|qtm?|ra(m|r)?|sea|sit|tar|tgz|torrent|txt|wav|wma|wmv|wpd|xls|xml|z|zip" }, "spamspan": { "m": "spamspan", "u": "u", "d": "d", "h": "h", "t": "t" } });
    //--><!]]>"""
>>> for i in re.findall(r'(?s)<!(.*?)>', html):
        print i


--//--
[CDATA[//
--
    jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, { "basePath": "/", "googleanalytics": { "trackOutbound": 1, "trackMailto": 1, "trackDownload": 1, "trackDownloadExtensions": "7z|aac|arc|arj|asf|asx|avi|bin|csv|doc|exe|flv|gif|gz|gzip|hqx|jar|jpe?g|js|mp(2|3|4|e?g)|mov(ie)?|msi|msp|pdf|phps|png|ppt|qtm?|ra(m|r)?|sea|sit|tar|tgz|torrent|txt|wav|wma|wmv|wpd|xls|xml|z|zip" }, "spamspan": { "m": "spamspan", "u": "u", "d": "d", "h": "h", "t": "t" } });
    //--
]]
```

OR

> extract conent using regex within `<!-- -->`

```
>>> for i in re.findall(r'(?s)<!--(.*?)-->', html):
        print i


//

    jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, { "basePath": "/", "googleanalytics": { "trackOutbound": 1, "trackMailto": 1, "trackDownload": 1, "trackDownloadExtensions": "7z|aac|arc|arj|asf|asx|avi|bin|csv|doc|exe|flv|gif|gz|gzip|hqx|jar|jpe?g|js|mp(2|3|4|e?g)|mov(ie)?|msi|msp|pdf|phps|png|ppt|qtm?|ra(m|r)?|sea|sit|tar|tgz|torrent|txt|wav|wma|wmv|wpd|xls|xml|z|zip" }, "spamspan": { "m": "spamspan", "u": "u", "d": "d", "h": "h", "t": "t" } });
    //
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: regular expression to extract  content  from " "

Answer (score 0):

Use a non-greedy regex with a `findall` search:

```
matches = re.findall(r'<!.*?>', string)
```

Comment: if i get all these string in a list (match) , is there ' s way to use this list to delete all the content in html text  which belongs to (match) list

Comment: Try `string = re.sub('<!.*?>', '', string)`